# Electron application appearantly unsolvable problem

Tags: javascript, multithreading, promise, electron

I am creating a scratch (https://scratch.mit.edu/) knockoff as a project using Electron with Node, and I want the application to be able to run more than one node at once. I have tried using both workers and promises, but both don't qualify enough to work for me.

Promises aren't good enough since i have to manually add await sleep()/ setTimeout calls for the promises to have actual time to run and execute the instuctions (and if i add more promises after the first Promise.All() call, which is a thing that does happen in my app, the first batch of promises will get the left over time of the 2nd batch as far as i can tell), which is a randabout way of getting a straight-forward functionallity.

Of course, threads are perfect for this, but impossible to implement since vanilla workers not only have no access to the dom which is a must, but also they are also unable to import modules. I also tried using the Node worker module, but it gives me an error if I run it from the renderer (details below), and running it from the main process has the the exact same problem as the vanilla workers

I mainly focused on getting it to work with threads, but i had little success. Using the require("worker_threads") module from the renderer gave me a "The V8 platform used by this instance of Node does not support creating Workers". I looked at the github issues, previous questions and even chatGPT (which is outdated to be fair) and nothing helped.

Is there some sort of black javascript magic I'm not aware of or do I have to use a 'await sleep()' function, which will give me time tradeoffs? (it's not flexible to the amount of nodes running, if there are too little, im wasting time waiting, but if there are too many it will become laggy)

Basically, while the promises will work, it has a tradeoff im not willing to accept until I'm desperate enough.

I don't really have codes to share besides specific test cases that probably won't tell anything more than I already did. Maybe I'm wrong about the await sleep, but as far as my test cases went as long as there is no 'await' that takes enough time, the entire application becomes stuck.

Comment: You should be able to structure this as an event-driven process without having to get too deep into the weeds. I'm not sure what issues you're having, there's no code for context here, but it sounds like you need to update your document(s) on a regular cycle, like [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) if you have access to that.